# What value is conditional logistic regression if two cohorts are already matched on everything of interest?

Tags: regression, logistic, matching, clogit

My situation is this:

- I am comparing two cohorts
- I have matched the two cohorts on all of the factors that I am interested in
- The two cohorts are already balanced on all of the factors that I would include in a regression

Questions:

- Is it appropriate to just report the univariate results?
- Would conditional logistic regression add anything to/change the results?

Comment: I'm assuming by univariate you mean bivariate, since you're comparing some measure (not matched) between the two cohorts. If so, then there shouldn't be any added value to regression.

Comment: I should be more precise, since I might be mis-using the word univariate. I mean would just running t-tests and chi sq/Fisher exact tests individually comparing the variables between cohorts be sufficient to present the results, or would doing cond logisitic regression add anything? I think that is what you're answering, and what I meant to ask, so thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a dataset that has the following variables: outcome (one or more of these), cohortID, covariates (many of these). If you've matched the two cohorts on all of the covariates, and your plan is to analyze the outcome(s) between groups using t-tests (or similar), then there should be no added value of incorporating the covariates into your analysis since the two cohorts will not differ (post-matching) on any of those variables.

You mention logistic regression specifically, which I assume means that one of your outcomes is coded (0,1) like whether an individual did graduate or did not graduate. You could use logistic regression including only the cohort identifier variable as a predictor. This should, however, give you substantively similar inference to a number of other tests suited for binary outcomes, like a difference-of-proportions test, the odds-ratio, or the risk ratio. If your outcome is not binary, then t-test, linear regression, or similar are the way to go.

Comment: Yes exactly, I have Cohort 1 and Cohort 2, matched on a large number of variables (comorbidities), and the outcomes that I am interested in are binary, hence the logistic regression. Thanks for confirming my intuition on this.